# Get back a JSON file from Azure-Blob in React

Tags: reactjs, azure-blob-storage

I have a react application that sends a JSON file by converting it into a string and then downloads it back. My issue is that when I am updating it (making changes in the JSON and re-uploading it to Azure Blob) and downloading it again; I need to refresh my React app to see the change/update. How to get this done in real-time without updating?

```js
async function main() {
  // Selecting  a container
  const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
        
  //This creates a blob and add content ==Models(Json file) to it
            
  const content=JSON.stringify(Models)
  const blobName="Models.json"
  const blockBlobClient=containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
  const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.upload(content,content.length)
  console.log(`Upload block blob ${blobName} successfully`, uploadBlobResponse.requestId);
}
```

I have JS code to upload the JSON("Models") file to azure-storage.

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  async function createBlob() {
    await ModelBlob();
    const res=await  ModelJsonDownload()
    const modelData= JSON.parse(res)
    setData(modelData)
    setisLoading(false)
                    
    //console.log(data.cube.props.position[0])
                
  }
  createBlob()
},[])
```

Here, I am downloading the JSON file once when the react app starts using `useEffect` hook.

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  async function createBlob(){
    //await ModelBlob();
    console.log("updating...")
    const res=await  ModelJsonDownload()
    const modelData= JSON.parse(res)
    props.setData(modelData)
    console.log("updated")
    props.setisLoading(false)
    console.log("runs on every color change")
    console.log(modelData.cube.props.color)
  }
  createBlob()
},[props.color])
```

Now, I have another `useEffect` hook for my dropdown. Basically, this runs on the `onChange` event of the dropdown. It again uploads the JSON file with different color and again downloads it. Right now, it is working only if I refresh my React app. I want it to work without refreshing the page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have updated it and added images of the code. can you please go through them and tell me where i am going wrong

Comment: Please do not add images of the code, instead insert the code as text so that it can be copied and tested.

Comment: Edited...kindly go through it

Comment: Looks good, made some changes as well.